# Is there one variable way to create single linked list in python

Tags: python-3.x, refactoring

So I have the below single linked list class:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

and now I create a single linked list from an array [-10,-3,0,5,9]

```
input = [-10,-3,0,5,9]
head = ListNode(input[0])
for idx, x in enumerate(input[1:]):
    if idx == 0:
        head.next = ListNode(x)
        temp = head.next
    else:
        temp.next = ListNode(x)
        temp = temp.next
```

Let's check my implementation:

```
while (head):
    print(head.val)
    head = head.next
```

the output is

```
-10
-3
0
5
9
```

now the output is correct. But as you saw, I used some ugly way of creating a single linked list instance, i.e., I used two variables: `temp` and `head`. Is there any way I can use only `head` or `temp`?

Comment: You should try to create insert method in your linked list class. And then use this method to insert the item in linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a decent implementation of a singly linked list, with a separate class for `ListNode` and `SinglyLinkedList`, in which the `ListNode` is a node in a singly-linked list whereas `SinglyLinkedList` is the singly-linked list which also supports the operations like prepend and append.

```
class ListNode:
    """
    A node in a singly-linked list.
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)


class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Create a new singly-linked list.
        Takes O(1) time.
        """
        self.head = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Return a string representation of the list.
        Takes O(n) time.
        """
        nodes = []
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            nodes.append(repr(curr))
            curr = curr.next
        return '[' + ', '.join(nodes) + ']'

    def prepend(self, data):
        """
        Insert a new element at the beginning of the list.
        Takes O(1) time.
        """
        self.head = ListNode(data=data, next=self.head)

    def append(self, data):
        """
        Insert a new element at the end of the list.
        Takes O(n) time.
        """
        if not self.head:
            self.head = ListNode(data=data)
            return
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next:
            curr = curr.next
        curr.next = ListNode(data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    singly_linked_list = SinglyLinkedList()
    print(singly_linked_list)

    input_array = [-10, -3, 0, 5, 9]
    for x in input_array:
        print(x)
        singly_linked_list.append(x)

    print(singly_linked_list)
```

Other implementations for the singly-linked list can be seen [here](https://dbader.org/blog/python-linked-list).

Hope it helps.